# Does IE9 and IE10 fully supports Local Storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am Using Local storage to keep track, if user opened a particular resource in tabs or not. In chrome and firefox I am able to achieve this whenever user try to load a resource in two different tabs my code gets notified on load activity. for example let I have resource R1 if user have opened the R1 resource then localStorage.getItem("R1") gives me some value which means Item is already opened in some different tab. But in IE9 and IE10 I am facing problem event when that item exist in localStorage some tabs gets correct value but some gets null value. ie. I Opened R1 in one tab  then i tried opening R1 in 3 different tabs two of then got R1 is already opened but one says it is not opened.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage

Answer (score 0):

Localstorage is fully supported by Ie9 and IE 10. To check visit caniuse website and type localstorage. Also you can check using modernizr.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage

Comment: Hi Swapnil thanks.
Time I am trying to get a value from localstorage asynchronously (using multiple tab) I am facing this problem but if i fetch(localStorage.getItem()) using a loop i get same value every time. even if I am not changing value in between is it some where related to synchronization?

Answer (score 0):

After some Trials I noticed In case of Internet explorer local Storage is not persistent across tabs. I made a page which updates a local storage in user operation after some operation in different tabs I noticed same key was having different values in different tabs under same domain. sample code :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="showError()" onbeforeunload="unloadFun()">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var timer;
    function showError(){
        if(localStorage["test"]){
            appendActionToLocalStorage("set");
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=localStorage["renew"];
        }
        timer=setInterval(function(){appendActionToLocalStorage("renew");},5000);
    }
    function appendActionToLocalStorage(operation){
      if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
        if(localStorage["opSeq"]){
          localStorage["opSeq"]=localStorage["opSeq"]+"-"+operation;
        }
        else{
          localStorage["opSeq"]=operation;
        }
      }
    }
    function funA(){
        appendActionToLocalStorage("setA");
    }
    function funB(){
        appendActionToLocalStorage("setB");
    }
    function funC(){
        appendActionToLocalStorage("setC");
    }
</script>       
<h1> 404 : Resource Not Found</h1>
<h2 id="message"></h2>
<a href="#" onclick="funA()">A</a>
<a href="#" onclick="funB()">B</a>
<a href="#" onclick="funC()">C</a>
</body>
</html>
```